# Azure Data Explorer-Compute calculated field values at ingestion time

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We have this table from an event with column A, but users always use column B, which is computed from function f(A). I don't want users to keep calling `extends B = f(A)` all the time.

How do I use update policy to create column B values at ingestion time instead? Thank you.

EDIT 1: I want column A and column B to be in the same table

Answer (score 3):

Using an update policy is an appropriate solution.

The official documentation includes a complete example for how to define the policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

You can find an additional example in this blog post: https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/update-policies.html

Comment: Right. But they both talk about different Source Table and Target Table. Can Source Table and Target Table be the same table?

Comment: no, source table and destination table are different. if you don't need to retain the data in its raw form in the source table, set the soft delete period for is to `0` in the table's retention policy (as mentioned/demonstrated in the documents previously linked-to)

Comment: then that won't work for my case then because I want to update column B based on column A in the same table. I just updated the question to highlight that